# How to add numbers in a mixed string C#

Tags: c#, .net

example = "I-000146.22.43.24"

In the example, I need to validate that the last number after the period isnt over 9. Currently is 24 and thats not valid.
01-08 is valid and anything over that isnt.

How can I add logic to check for this?

Comment: Try following :             string example = "I-000146.22.43.24";
            int lastPeriod = example.LastIndexOf(".");
            string lastNumberStr = example.Substring(lastPeriod + 1);
            int lastNumber = int.Parse(lastNumberStr);

Comment: can you have more than 2 numbers after the last period.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex). The regex pattern would be something like this:

```
^.+\.(0?[0-8])$
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F7yjqK/1)**.

**C# example:**

```
string pattern = @"^.+\.(0?[0-8])$";
string[] inputs = new [] { "I-000146.22.43.24", "I-000146.22.43.09", 
                           "I-000146.22.43.08", "xxxxxxx.07" };
foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    if (match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine($"The input is valid. Last number is '{match.Groups[1].Value}'.");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("The input is not valid.");
}
```

**Output:**

```
The input is not valid.
The input is not valid.
The input is valid. Last number is '08'.
The input is valid. Last number is '07'.
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/OAOM1930)**.

Comment: I like the mighty `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` :) Also, `^.+` is just a waste of time in your pattern.

Comment: @NetMage You're right. I left it as a placeholder in case the OP wants to validate the first part of the string in some way but ended up not mentioning that in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Linq`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        String[] tests = new string[3] {"I-000146.22.43.24", "I-000146.22.43.9", "I-000146.22.43.a"};
        foreach (string test in tests) {
            Console.WriteLine ($"{test} is a valid string: {isValidString (test)}");
        }
    }

    private static bool isValidString (string str) {
        var lastNumString = str.Split ('.').Last();
        return isSingleDigit (lastNumString);
    }

    private static bool isSingleDigit (string numString) {
        int number;
        bool success = Int32.TryParse (numString, out number);
        if (success) {
            return number >= 0 && number <= 9;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
I-000146.22.43.24 is a valid string: False
I-000146.22.43.9 is a valid string: True
I-000146.22.43.a is a valid string: False
```